# Cheap alternatives to avoid tire punctures

Tags: tire, puncture, innertube

If you head to Walmart and see the slime bike liners for in the tire to stop goatheads and small nailes from actually running the tire.
Is there anything around the house or shed that can be used also?
Also the slime ones only seem to not cover the side of the tire wall. I do rock and outdoor bike riding and once hit a soft dirt patch that sunk my tire and a small nail got in from the side.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want punctures, you have to fork over the money for puncture-resistant tires. This is how the universe works.

Comment: Yep, puncture-resistant tires are the way to go.  Generally about 50% more than regular tires, but well worth it.

Comment: Can we assume this is about 26" tires/ standard mountain bike tires?

Comment: Also once they're on, keep them inflated to the right pressure. Then cross your fingers.

Comment: The best advice is to keep the tyres properly inflated (pressure repels sharps really well) but, off-road, you may have good reason to explicitly run them soft, so that's not going to work so well for you in those times.

Comment: Thanks, all very good answers and insights. I suppose having the thickened liners would work best, and usually i do have lowered air pressure when i go out onto wet terrian, but not so much i ruin the rim. Ill get a few old tires and some liners and see what works best, though ill bet on the liners that cost money. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Puncture resistant tires and liners are hard to DIY since they are made from kevlar and other specialty materials which are not easy to come by on the consumer market.

Flat protection opions:

Puncture resistant tires $35 to $80 a tire - most expensive, best protection, only good for the life of the tire. My favorite lightweight ones are panaracer t-serve, most protection panaracer ribmo.

Tire Liners - $15-$25 a set- cheaper, reusable when you get new tires, adds a bit to rotating weight.  Mr Tuffy and Slime brands are available. I haven't used these personally.

Tubes with sealant - $10-$15 per tire - will seal small punctures with a liquid sealant. This is pretty much the same liquid in tubeless tire setups. This can have mixed results. Slime can get messy and clog valves. I don't think these are worth it.

Really, none of these will prevent pinch flats either. Your best bet is to use one of the first two options and keep tires inflated to the proper PSI regularly. Always carry a patch kit and tools to fix a flat and a spare tube is nice to have as well, it pays to be prepared.

Comment: Tubeless systems have also come a long way since this question was posed. Many different options from road to mtb to fat bike sizes. Different Sealants are effective at sealing punctures quickly with different properties for each brand. I've been riding MTBs now for a few years with tubeless tires and have very few flats due to this. They can also be effective for things that the author mentions, such as goatheads.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, bad advice following capitalist bad advice.  How about this (I wrote this yesterday for bicycle hacker exchange):

Goatheads (and that is what most from Southern California to Texas call them) are NASTY! They are proof that nature can build an armored micro-sticker capable of punching through Kevlar on a whim! Believe it or not, after TONS of failures from Tuffy liners to Rhinodillo liners, I made my own that actually worked! The problem is the plastic they use. All the liners are using Urethane. Forget that, use PET (Polyethylene).  Simply go to the store, buy 1-qty 2-liter soda per tire you need a liner in. Make sure the soda is a flat-wall bottle, like a Pepsi or Mt. Dew (sorry, Coke won't work on this one). Now, cut the top off and bottom off, until all you have is a straight cylinder of plastic. Now, take a marker and draw a spiral line around the bottle - I use a compass, so my width stays standard as  I spiral around the bottle body. You can get a strip out to about 85-inches (around 28...maybe 29" diameter tire) out of one bottle. Now, make sure you use some 200-grit sandpaper and knock all those edges down, so they don't pinch or cut the tube. Then, just put them into the tire and re-assemble. Costs $10 less than a commercial liner, 10x tougher than any liner you can buy, no significant weight gain on the bike, and I personally can't tell a lot of 'harder ride' quality either. I have YET to have a goathead puncture this liner!

Now, for $3 in soda, you can enjoy a week of soda-decadence AND fix your tires to be nearly 'unpuncturable', without putting a corporate logo inside your bike tires!

Comment: definitely an interesting idea , id be curious to see a side by side comparison with some tests to back it up.

Comment: Nice idea - how wide is the cut strip ?   And do you do anything extra at the end, like overlap or butt-join?

Comment: How long have you been running this for? I'm curious because I once had a sidewall tear that I fixed with a Lezyne Boot, finished the ride and totally forgot about... Until a couple of months later when the inner tube ended up with a hole in it, as on each revolution the tyre flexes, so the edge of the boot rubs against the inner tube, and eventually wears through. I'm thinking that the join (as queried by @Criggie) might have a similar wearing through problem.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the expensive tire liners like Mr Tuffy or SpinSkins, as an "eco friendly", re-cyclable alternative, you may want to try using a discarded tire in reasonable condition, the same size as your bike's tires, as a "liner". You'd want a smooth tread, no mountain bike tire treads. Then you CAREFULLY cut the bead off of the tire using whatever sharp tool works best for you. Some type of shears or scissors should work well. Then you can insert the trimmed tire carcass between the tube and tire and put the tire back on your wheel with the extra protection inside. Of course this "tire liner" will give some extra protection from the ordinary punctures you may get, and even protects the sidewall better, but it's no Mr Tuffy. It is usually free though, and that is a plus when you're "experimenting!" Most bike shops will gladly give you the old worn out tires in your size. Just be sure to ask for them.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Tyvek on my commuting bike.  Installation is similar to the other answers in this thread, cut strips and put between tube and tire. It successfully reduced my flatting frequency to almost nil in the past 2 years (~ 15 miles of riding city streets per day).  I remember maybe a few flats per year before the tyvek. I doubt if the stuff will handle repeated goat heads. I guess you could double it up?  It probably wont stop nails in the sidewalls.

On the plus side it is dirt cheap, even free. See if there's some in the trash bin at a construction site. The USPS provides tyvek envelopes free for Priority mail users. Perhaps see if someone is throwing out their mail?

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of along the same lines as what @Benzo said.

1. Get a good track pump.  It doesn't have to be expensive, but $25-$50 can get you a pretty good pump, that will last you a life time. Before I got a track pump, I got quite a few flats, now I get almost none.  This may matter more with high pressure road tires.  The better quality the pump, the more you will use it, and the smaller chance that you will get a pinch flat from low pressure.
2. I've used Mr. Tuffy Tire liners on my road bike and swear by them. Rode over a broken beer bottle with these in and didn't get a flat.  Personally, I think they are well worth the $15-$20 that they cost, and are probably the cheapest way to prevent punctures.  At least on my experience with road bikes. But then again, they won't do anything against pinch flats, so I restate, get a good pump (or suffer with a bad pump) and make sure you tires are properly inflated.
3. Us an old dead tube to line the tire. Cut it so that it can be wrapped around the other tire.  This is basically the same idea as Tuffy tape, but less resistant to punctures. This can be done so that it does protect from the sides.  The extra layer is similar to using extra thick tubes, without paying for extra thick tubes every time you need to replace your tubes.

If you look at it from a cost perpective, even buying good tires can and often will cost less in the long run. Spending $100 on tires means you don't spend so much on other ways of preventing flats.  You don't have to spend $15-$20 on Tuffy tape. You don't have to spend $10 on a new set of tubes a couple times a year, or spend a bunch of your time fixing punctures.

Answer (score -3):

My I recommend you look at purchasing tubeless tyres, they can be expensive but no more so than ones purchased and they are pretty smart , if you look about online you will find them to the dedicated sizes.

Comment: Are tubeless tires actually better for this?